# Display irregular timestamp on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe. And I would like to plot x and y but replace the x axis tick labels with the endTime column on.  However, I just cannot get this right.

```
                  endTime    x         y
0 2021-06-29 09:15:44.097  0.0       inf
1 2021-06-29 09:17:50.434  1.0  2.718282
2 2021-06-29 09:21:32.209  2.0  0.824361
3 2021-06-29 09:23:48.657  3.0  0.465204
4 2021-06-29 09:29:55.713  4.0  0.321006

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,sharex=False,dpi=400)
ax.plot(abc['x'],abc['y'],linewidth = 1, color='black')
ax.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',labelsize=6)
ax.set_xticklabels(abc['endTime'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_ha('right')
    label.set_rotation(45)
    label.set_fontsize(5)
```

[image]

The actual dataframe is as follow:

```
{'endTime': {0: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:15:44.097000'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:17:50.434000'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:21:32.209000'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:23:48.657000'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:29:55.713000'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:30:39.039000'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:32:02.137000'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:32:53.199000'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:34:26.447000'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:35:32.147000'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:36:58.669000'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:39:01.664000'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:39:54.868000'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:41:12.514000'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:42:46.969000'),
  15: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:44:17.882000'),
  16: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:45:34.855000'),
  17: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:47:46.924000'),
  18: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:49:42.807000'),
  19: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:50:17.589000'),
  20: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:51:27.592000'),
  21: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:53:06.344000'),
  22: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:54:19.235000'),
  23: Timestamp('2021-06-29 09:56:42.898000'),
  24: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:00:12.240000'),
  25: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:02:11.541000'),
  26: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:06:13.520000'),
  27: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:09:40.064000'),
  28: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:12:38.347000'),
  29: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:15:18.936000'),
  30: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:18:12.151000'),
  31: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:21:29.921000'),
  32: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:25:07.076000'),
  33: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:28:33.882000'),
  34: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:33:32.048000'),
  35: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:37:04.144000'),
  36: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:40:15.729000'),
  37: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:44:06.881000'),
  38: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:48:02.841000'),
  39: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:53:14.078000'),
  40: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:55:24.998000'),
  41: Timestamp('2021-06-29 10:58:54.023000'),
  42: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:04:57.751000'),
  43: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:08:27.457000'),
  44: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:11:59.912000'),
  45: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:17:53.474000'),
  46: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:22:38.469000'),
  47: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:26:35.577000'),
  48: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:30:00.279000'),
  49: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:35:41.830000'),
  50: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:40:05.413000'),
  51: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:45:28.679000'),
  52: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:50:43.851000'),
  53: Timestamp('2021-06-29 11:57:31.521000'),
  54: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:00:39.244000'),
  55: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:04:57.323000'),
  56: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:08:34.488000'),
  57: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:13:02.859000'),
  58: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:19:39.836000'),
  59: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:24:29.931000'),
  60: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:29:02.992000'),
  61: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:32:15.414000'),
  62: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:36:01.976000'),
  63: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:42:32.769000'),
  64: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:47:46.070000'),
  65: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:52:59.930000'),
  66: Timestamp('2021-06-29 13:59:45.501000'),
  67: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:04:46.406000'),
  68: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:07:28.696000'),
  69: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:08:44.476000'),
  70: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:14:47.081000'),
  71: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:22:41.006000'),
  72: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:30:08.780000'),
  73: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:37:50.977000'),
  74: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:41:11.529000'),
  75: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:45:01.870000'),
  76: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:49:46.199000'),
  77: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:51:22.406000'),
  78: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:53:23.328000'),
  79: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:55:45.348000'),
  80: Timestamp('2021-06-29 14:59:15.975000'),
  81: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:02:59.465000'),
  82: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:07:11.711000'),
  83: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:10:45.915000'),
  84: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:15:10.744000'),
  85: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:19:07.360000'),
  86: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:23:14.322000'),
  87: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:26:24.208000'),
  88: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:30:24.773000'),
  89: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:36:15.559000'),
  90: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:41:07.963000'),
  91: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:47:30.031000'),
  92: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:52:36.487000'),
  93: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:56:23.028000'),
  94: Timestamp('2021-06-29 15:59:01.159000'),
  95: Timestamp('2021-06-29 16:01:14.504000'),
  96: Timestamp('2021-06-29 16:06:21.536000'),
  97: Timestamp('2021-06-29 16:09:06.893000'),
  98: Timestamp('2021-06-29 16:14:42.689000'),
  99: Timestamp('2021-06-29 16:25:03.275000')},
 'x': {0: 0.0,
  1: 1.0,
  2: 2.0,
  3: 3.0,
  4: 4.0,
  5: 5.0,
  6: 6.0,
  7: 7.0,
  8: 8.0,
  9: 9.0,
  10: 10.0,
  11: 11.0,
  12: 12.0,
  13: 13.0,
  14: 14.0,
  15: 15.0,
  16: 16.0,
  17: 17.0,
  18: 18.0,
  19: 19.0,
  20: 20.0,
  21: 21.0,
  22: 22.0,
  23: 23.0,
  24: 24.0,
  25: 25.0,
  26: 26.0,
  27: 27.0,
  28: 28.0,
  29: 29.0,
  30: 30.0,
  31: 31.0,
  32: 32.0,
  33: 33.0,
  34: 34.0,
  35: 35.0,
  36: 36.0,
  37: 37.0,
  38: 38.0,
  39: 39.0,
  40: 40.0,
  41: 41.0,
  42: 42.0,
  43: 43.0,
  44: 44.0,
  45: 45.0,
  46: 46.0,
  47: 47.0,
  48: 48.0,
  49: 49.0,
  50: 50.0,
  51: 51.0,
  52: 52.0,
  53: 53.0,
  54: 54.0,
  55: 55.0,
  56: 56.0,
  57: 57.0,
  58: 58.0,
  59: 59.0,
  60: 60.0,
  61: 61.0,
  62: 62.0,
  63: 63.0,
  64: 64.0,
  65: 65.0,
  66: 66.0,
  67: 67.0,
  68: 68.0,
  69: 69.0,
  70: 70.0,
  71: 71.0,
  72: 72.0,
  73: 73.0,
  74: 74.0,
  75: 75.0,
  76: 76.0,
  77: 77.0,
  78: 78.0,
  79: 79.0,
  80: 80.0,
  81: 81.0,
  82: 82.0,
  83: 83.0,
  84: 84.0,
  85: 85.0,
  86: 86.0,
  87: 87.0,
  88: 88.0,
  89: 89.0,
  90: 90.0,
  91: 91.0,
  92: 92.0,
  93: 93.0,
  94: 94.0,
  95: 95.0,
  96: 96.0,
  97: 97.0,
  98: 98.0,
  99: 99.0},
 'y': {0: inf,
  1: 2.718281828459045,
  2: 0.8243606353500641,
  3: 0.46520414169536317,
  4: 0.32100635417193535,
  5: 0.24428055163203397,
  6: 0.1968934021442743,
  7: 0.16479499927072966,
  8: 0.1416435566333533,
  9: 0.12416878541576264,
  10: 0.11051709180756478,
  11: 0.09956085817042402,
  12: 0.09057533746010242,
  13: 0.08307376918678358,
  14: 0.07671724505116398,
  15: 0.07126260704981642,
  16: 0.06653090368236621,
  17: 0.062387533036807656,
  18: 0.058729319153346476,
  19: 0.05547585487325276,
  20: 0.052563554818801206,
  21: 0.04994147844694904,
  22: 0.0475683379634032,
  23: 0.04541031690899021,
  24: 0.043439454382916305,
  25: 0.041632430967695526,
  26: 0.03996964453633811,
  27: 0.03843449831943464,
  28: 0.03701284647909522,
  29: 0.035692557998043696,
  30: 0.03446317045045247,
  31: 0.03331561276838431,
  32: 0.03224198148434696,
  33: 0.031235358794543675,
  34: 0.030289663602118867,
  35: 0.029399528772330267,
  36: 0.028560199373269844,
  37: 0.027767447833407847,
  38: 0.027017502824254296,
  39: 0.0263069893464087,
  40: 0.025632878013110722,
  41: 0.024992441925521802,
  42: 0.024383219846499493,
  43: 0.02380298462536526,
  44: 0.023249716020602763,
  45: 0.022721577222185183,
  46: 0.02221689449911207,
  47: 0.021734139497433816,
  48: 0.021271913794689738,
  49: 0.020828935382242928,
  50: 0.020404026800535116,
  51: 0.019996104696205556,
  52: 0.01960417060620258,
  53: 0.019227302803948985,
  54: 0.018864649067480945,
  55: 0.018515420250202103,
  56: 0.0181788845522312,
  57: 0.01785436240487598,
  58: 0.01754122189302606,
  59: 0.01723887465061758,
  60: 0.01694677217310435,
  61: 0.01666440249833668,
  62: 0.016391287213615297,
  63: 0.016126978752130948,
  64: 0.015871057946666964,
  65: 0.015623131812453053,
  66: 0.015382831534515036,
  67: 0.015149810637850779,
  68: 0.014923743321347438,
  69: 0.014704322938598422,
  70: 0.014491260610729258,
  71: 0.014284283958041898,
  72: 0.014083135938771927,
  73: 0.013887573784552722,
  74: 0.01369736802332,
  75: 0.013512301581391233,
  76: 0.013332168957335343,
  77: 0.01315677546102486,
  78: 0.01298593651194874,
  79: 0.012819476991470978,
  80: 0.01265723064425793,
  81: 0.012499039524574767,
  82: 0.012344753483575723,
  83: 0.01219422969409067,
  84: 0.01204733220974755,
  85: 0.011903931555570808,
  86: 0.011763904347465158,
  87: 0.011627132938234756,
  88: 0.011493505088003843,
  89: 0.011362913657098819,
  90: 0.011235256319625976,
  91: 0.01111043529613601,
  92: 0.01098835710390777,
  93: 0.010868932323511311,
  94: 0.010752075380425403,
  95: 0.010637704340589017,
  96: 0.010525740718860394,
  97: 0.010416109299443053,
  98: 0.010308737967415375,
  99: 0.010203557550571063}}
```

Comment: It sounds like you would like the x axis tick marks and labels to appear at the actual timestamp values rather than equally spaced across the x axis.

Comment: **I would like to plot x and y but later on display the endTime column on x-axis** results in a misrepresentation of the data, because the Timestamp is not at a regular interval.

Comment: In any case, passing `'endTime'` to `x=`, as it should be,, results in the rest of the code working as expected: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6CDN.png)